# axlsx_rails gem: how to display leading zeros in Excel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

I am using rails gem 'axlsx_rails' to generate Excel sheets. I have strings in my database with leading zeros. But, by default, the column is coming with "General" format. So it does not display the leading zeros.

How do I specify the style so that I can display the leading zeroes? In other words, how do I generate a "Text" type column in Excel?

Answer (score 5):

```
worksheet.add_row ['001'], :types => [:string]
```

Comment: what if wee have multiple cells in row and we want to apply this on only one cell and cell position is random.

Answer (score 0):

Add `'` character at the start of your string. This wont change the format of the field but it will display leading zeros in Excel cell

Comment: This is displaying ' in the cell, how can I avoid it? Leading zeroes are coming fine.

Comment: It depends on how you will interact with the values in the cell. Cell will only show the string without `'` but if you select the cell, you will see `'` in the formula bar. If you just use the value in the cell to calculate something, it will discard the leading `'` and only use rest of the value in the cell

Comment: Excel is displaying the `'` even if the cell is not selected. I am using Excel on Mac.

Comment: From what I understand, Excel on Mac works different to how it works on windows. Sorry, I have no experience with Excel on Mac

Answer (score 0):

In your `.xlsx.wxlsx` file add a new format, something like this:

```
format = workbook.add_format()
format.set_text_wrap()
worksheet.write(0, 0, "Some long text to wrap in a cell", format)
```

Reference: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html

Comment: No, I am using sheet.add_row
    `date_cell = s.add_style(format_code: "dd-mm-yyyy")
    sheet.add_row [my_string, my_date], style: [nil, date_cell]`
The problem is with my_string

Comment: @user1575148 Your string is fine, all you have todo is change the format of your cell like I mentioned above!

Comment: How can I do that with add_row and style: ?

Comment: According to http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html your problem can only be solved by adding a format. Styles are just for colouring/borders etc.

Answer (score 0):

real life example where code can be leading zeros

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

wb = xlsx_package.workbook

wb.add_worksheet(name: "Orders") do |sheet|
  sheet.add_row %w[code name quantity]
  order.product_items.each do |product_item|
   sheet.add_row [product_item[:code], product_item[:name], product_item[:quantity]], types: [:string, :string, :integer]
  end
end
```